# OpenCL Dot Product

Tags: gpu, opencllink

I have to calculate billions of dot products. My current implementation uses `Compile` to generate `C` code and it's very fast (10s of seconds). But, I was wondering if I could make it faster by using my GPU (AMD 6670). Unfortunately I don't have an NVIDIA card since it seems that `CUDADot` is implemented.

I'm trying to use the OpenCL `DotProduct` code in `FileNameJoin[{$OpenCLLinkPath, "SupportFiles", "DotProduct.cl"}]`

code below:

```
src = "/*
 * Copyright 1993-2009 NVIDIA Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * NVIDIA Corporation and its licensors retain all intellectual property and 
 * proprietary rights in and to this software and related documentation. 
 * Any use, reproduction, disclosure, or distribution of this software 
 * and related documentation without an express license agreement from
 * NVIDIA Corporation is strictly prohibited.
 * 
 */

 __kernel void DotProduct (__global float* a, __global float* b, __global float* c, mint iNumElements)
{
    // find position in global arrays
    int iGID = get_global_id(0);

    // bound check (equivalent to the limit on a 'for' loop for standard/serial C code
    if (iGID >= iNumElements)
    {   
        return; 
    }

    // process 
    int iInOffset = iGID << 2;
    c[iGID] = a[iInOffset] * b[iInOffset] 
               + a[iInOffset + 1] * b[iInOffset + 1]
               + a[iInOffset + 2] * b[iInOffset + 2]
               + a[iInOffset + 3] * b[iInOffset + 3];
}"
```

I have managed to load the OpenCL function and compute a single DotProdct but this is mostely useless. I've been going over the instructions but I can't seem to figure out how to run many dot products in parallel (the whole point of using the GPU).

```
srcf = FileNameJoin[{$OpenCLLinkPath, "SupportFiles", "DotProduct.cl"}]

OpenCLDotProduct = 
  OpenCLFunctionLoad[{srcf}, 
   "DotProduct", {{"Float"}, {"Float"}, {"Float"}, _Integer}, {16, 
    16}];

output = {0};
a = {1., 2., 2.};
b = {1., 2., 2.};
OpenCLDotProduct[a, b, output, 3]

(*

output -> {{1., 2., 2.}, {1., 2., 2.}, {9.}}

*)
```

This is correct, great. However, I can't figure out how to do more than a.b:

```
output = {0, 0};
a = {1., 2., 2.};
b = {1., 2., 2.};
c = {3., 2., 8.};
OpenCLDotProduct[{a, c}, b, output, 6]

(*

output -> {{{1., 2., 2.}, {3., 2., 8.}}, {1., 2., 2.}, {18., 68.}}

*)
```

I can't figure out what this output means or what the proper syntax is to do multiple dotproducts. I'm also not sure if this implementation is even fast. I found a blog describing another implementation but I haven't been able to compile it (http://www.openclblog.com/2012/11/opencl-and-dot-product.html).

Comment: If you are using a Mac, be careful: it may be possible to run the opencl code either on the CPU or the GPU and the CPU *may* be the default.

Comment: @Szabolcs I use both but at the moment I've been working on Win7 x64. My Macbook Air is slower than my PC and it only has the integrated Intel GPU.

Comment: The problem is that you can't do this directly using the out-of-the-box solution for a dot product, since GPU-s are directly helpful for massively parallel problems, while this one directly is not. What I would do is to glue all vectors you want to multiple into two large vectors, and pass them to GPU together with a list of lengths. Then, you will have to write your own custom thread scheduler, so that effectively a thread which is finished with one vector pair is rescheduled to another one. Should be doable, but some work. Besides, you need a really powerful GPU for all this to pay off.

Comment: As an alternative, you may look for some Map-Reduce frameworks for GPUs, such as [this](http://www.cse.ust.hk/gpuqp/Mars.html). I never tried those, and it is probably also quite a bit of work. But the advantage here is that problems like your can be treated by Map-Reduce more directly and universally, while the first approach I suggested is not universal.

Comment: Also, just to stick with convention, it's best to stick with lower case starting letters for functions. I was confused for a second, thinking, "I didn't know mathematica had an OpenCLDotProduct function already defined!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is expecting vectors of length 4, and an equal number of `a` vectors and `b` vectors.

For example:

```
n = 10^7;
a = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {n, 4}];
b = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {n, 4}];
output = ConstantArray[0., n];

AbsoluteTiming[
 rOpenCL = Last @ OpenCLDotProduct[a, b, output, n];]

(*  {1.2324022, Null}  *)
```

The OpenCL is faster than *Mathematica*

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 rMMA = MapThread[Dot, {a, b}];]

 (*  {15.2568268, Null}  *)
```

But compiling to C is faster

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}, {y, _Real, 2}}, MapThread[Dot, {x, y}], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

AbsoluteTiming[rC = cf[a, b];]

(*  {1.0140017, Null}  *)
```

Also the OpenCL code is less accurate as it uses single precision:

```
Max[Abs[rOpenCL - rMMA]]
(*  0.0000396708  *)

Max[Abs[rC - rMMA]]
(*  0.  *)
```

I recompiled the OpenCL function with the actual dot product calculation completely stripped out, and found that the timing barely changed - just copying the data to and from the GPU takes almost all the time here.

Comment: Thanks very much. I guess I'll stick with `C`. Also if you write the compiled function to be `Listable` and `Parallelized` its a bit faster `Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}}, Dot[x.y], 
 CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
 Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed"}]`

Comment: @s0rce, you're welcome. The real benefit of having GPU code for this sort of ultra-simple procedure is when you already have data on the GPU. A while ago I wrote a CUDA kernel to do an element-by-element 2D complex array multiply. As a standalone function it was slower than just doing `C = A B` in *Mathematica*, but the overall calculation was an iterative process including 2D FFTs (where the GPU really shines). Having the multiply function in CUDA meant I could load the GPU memory once, do everything on the GPU and then copy the result back to the CPU.

Comment: @SimonWoods, Would you mind posting that code if you still have it?  I'd like to do something similar with FFTs and multiplying matrices, but I am a newbie to opencl and cuda programming. So, having a working example would be a great help to me. Thanks, Craig

Comment: @CraigCarter, sorry but I don't have permission to share that code, I wrote it but I do not own it.